# react: почему не изменяются состояния компонента

Tags: reactjs, setstate, ant-design, usestate

Есть компонент со таймером обратного отсчёта от Ant Design (`Statistic.Countdown`).

Хотя, чтоб в зависимости от того сколько времени осталось до 0 он отрисовывался в разных стилях.

Делаю следующий код:

```
import { useState } from 'react';    
import { Statistic } from 'antd';   

const Header = (props) => {

  // контроль состояний    
  const [timerState, setTimerState] = useState(0);

  // стили для разных состояний
  const styles = [
    {deadline: 10, style: {color: '#000000', textAlign: 'center'}},
    {deadline: 5, style: {color: '#bb0000', textAlign: 'center'}},
    {deadline: 0, style: {color: '#bb0000', textAlign: 'center', animation: 'neon 1s infinite'}}
  ]

  // колбэк: изменение времени таймера
  const handleChangeTimer = (timer) => {    
    if (timer <= 1000 * styles[timerState]?.deadline) {
      setTimerState(timerState + 1);      
    }
  }
    
  // отрисовать компонент
  const currentStyle = styles[states.timer_state < styles.length ? states.timer_state : styles.length - 1].style;

  return (
      <Statistic.Countdown title='Время выполнения' value={props.timer} format='mm:ss' valueStyle={currentStyle} onChange={handleChangeTimer} /> 
  );
}
```

В результате `handleChangeTimer` регулярно вызывается, `timer` уменьшается, `setTimerState` вызывается, а вот `timerState` никак не меняется и остается на одном значении (0).

В чем может быть дело?

Кстати если при этом как-то тормошить `Statistic.Countdown`, например там же устанавливать через новое состояние ему `value`, то `setTimerState` начинает работать. Например:

```
  // контроль состояний    
  const [timerState, setTimerState] = useState({
      state: 0,
      deadline: props.timer
  });

  // колбэк: изменение времени таймера
  const handleChangeTimer = (timer) => {    
    if (timer <= 1000 * styles[timerState]?.deadline) {
      setTimerState({
          timerState.state: timerState + 1,
          deadline: Date.now() + timer);      
    }
  }

  return (
      <Statistic.Countdown title='Время выполнения' value={timerState.deadline} format='mm:ss' valueStyle={currentStyle} onChange={handleChangeTimer} /> 
  );
```

Почему так?

Comment: по простому все тут асинхронно, ты не знаеш в какой участок времени какой у тебя timerState, что 
бы использовать предидушее состояние надо юзать специальную конструкцию setState((prevState) => ....)

Comment: кстати что за states?

Comment: states - это я код недочистил, подправил сейчас

Comment: шя разбираюсь, тут другой нюанс, разберусь дам знать

Answer (score 0):

```js
предлагаю пользоватся так, а не через свой стейт (то есть следить за таймером исключительно)

что касается проблемы:

внутри Countdown используется setInterval что в свою очередь замыкает переменную timerState. по этому она всегда 0

то что у них под капотом написано ведет к тому что timerState должен быть состоянием и изменение этого состояния внутри handleChangeTimer должно тригернуть на вызов onChange уже с актуальным timerState НО каким значением обновить timerState что то не особо понятно. (как не пробовал у меня секунды тикали в х3 скорости)

const Header = () => {
  const [timerState] = useState(Date.now() + timeout);
  const [deadline, setDeadline] = useState(7);

  const styles = {
    7: {
      color: 'green',
    },
    5: {
      color: 'blue',
    },
    3: {
      color: 'red',
    },
  };

  const handleChangeTimer = (timer: number) => {
    const roundedTimer = Math.round(timer / 1000);
    if (styles[roundedTimer]) {
      setDeadline(roundedTimer);
    }
  };

  const currentStyle = styles[deadline];

  return (
    <Statistic.Countdown
      title="Время выполнения"
      value={timerState}
      format="mm:ss"
      valueStyle={currentStyle}
      onChange={handleChangeTimer}
    />
  );
};
```